# Convert sql query with arithmetic operators to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I have the following sql table

```
create table PurchasingShipments (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ShipmentID AS 'PSID' + RIGHT('00000000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(8)), 8) PERSISTED PRIMARY KEY,
    Title varchar(300),
    NoOfPieces integer,
    PricePerPiece money,
    ActualCostPerPiece money,
    Micelleneous money,
    Year integer,
    Month integer,
    date integer,
    TransportCost money,
    SupplierCommission money,   
)
```

And I do have the following SQL query to retrieve data from the above table:

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(date) AS 'year',
    SUM(NoOfPieces * PricePerPiece + Micelleneous + TransportCost + SupplierCommission) AS 'cost'
FROM PurchasingShipments
GROUP BY YEAR(date)
```

I'm using visual studio 2013 with entityframework 6. So I need to convert the above query to LINQ. How can I do that?

Comment: Why `date` is integer data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be something like:

```
var qry = from ps in PurchasingShipmentsEntity
    group ps by ps.Year into grp
    select new
    {
         Year = grp.Key,
         Cost = grp.Sum(x=> x.NoOfPieces * x.PricePerPiece + x.Micelleneous + x.TransportCost + x.SupplierCommission)
    };
```